# Is it possible to log all items installed, modified, removed? (Ubuntu Server 14.04.2)

Tags: server, uninstall, log

Is it possible to log automatically when things are installed, removed or modified at my Ubuntu server? It would be nice if I can view the log to see what I (as root) did modify, install, remove.

I'll hope this is possible and I'll hope someone can explain me how to setup such thing.

Kind regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 2):

It's already done (at least for things installed via Softwarecenter etc.). Please check `/var/log/dpkg.log` or as mention in the comments via `/var/log/apt/history.log`

Comment: Or: `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Answer (score 0):

In GUI you can do it from Ubuntu Software Center, go to the tab History and there you can find every thing.

But now for you as you using **ubuntu server 14.04** then the above is not valid so you should search from files, basically those history is located under:

```
/var/log/dpkg.log*
```

And

```
/var/log/apt/history.log*
```

And Why I put `*` because there is more than one file as stated above, For example:

```
$ ls /var/log/dpkg.log
dpkg.log        dpkg.log.12.gz  dpkg.log.5.gz   dpkg.log.9.gz
dpkg.log.1      dpkg.log.2.gz   dpkg.log.6.gz   
dpkg.log.10.gz  dpkg.log.3.gz   dpkg.log.7.gz   
dpkg.log.11.gz  dpkg.log.4.gz   dpkg.log.8.gz
```

So indeed log will be compressed and moved when it reaches some size.

Now to know for example let's know recently installed packages that were installed via any method

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ "
```

Example output:

```
2015-07-01 13:56:40 install htop <none> 1.0.1-1
```

let's know recently installed packages that were removed

```
 cat /var/log/dpkg.log.1 | grep "\ remove\ "
```

Example output:

```
2015-06-02 08:34:18 remove dconf-tools 0.12.0-0ubuntu1.1 <none>
2015-06-04 13:15:06 remove bitmeteros 0.7.6 <none>
2015-06-04 13:16:25 remove bitmeteros 0.7.6 <none>
2015-06-08 11:34:33 remove jack 3.1.1+cvs20050801-26build1 <none>
2015-06-09 08:35:05 remove nautilus-dropbox 0.7.1-2 <none>
2015-06-26 11:53:29 remove dconf 0.5.1-2 <none>
```